# Get cells 'valueBefore' on change in Office.js excel

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, office-addins, exceljs

I am working on a Excel Web Add-In using Office.js.
I need to get changed cells Values before the cells change.
For one changed cell I can get Excel.ChangedEventDetail and from there get valueBefore:

```
cellChange = async (event: Excel.TableChangedEventArgs): Promise<any> =>
{
    await Excel.run({delayForCellEdit: true}, async context =>
    {
        let details: Excel.ChangedEventDetail = event.details;
        let value = details.valueBefore;
    }
}
```

But this does not work with range of changed cells. If I change more than one cell 'details' value is 'undefined'. Is there a way to get cell value before change for each cell from range?

Comment: Would you please share me your scenario, i would like to see how we can support you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, onChangedEvent was designed to return the single value change [detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetchangedeventargs?view=excel-js-preview#details). because the [payload size limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#excel-add-ins), as cell content can be huge, if we support multiple cells, user may copy and paste a big range which would big possibility to hit the payload size limit. Therefore we limit to return single cell detail in this event.

Therefore, I would suggest that you could submit your request on [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563), and upvote your request. Thanks.

[image]

But it would you great if you could share your scenario, therefore I see if we can help you to unblock this scenario? thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my excel table I populate data from different sources and some cells should not be changed, I set background color to this cell and depending on this color I can prevent cell change. But in case user changes range of cell values, I go thought each cell and check it's color, and depending on that (let's say color is gray) I want to restore value that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: If you would like to aovid user change the special cells, I think you may use lock the cell feature and protect the sheet. therefore end user cannot change the protected cell

Comment: I can't lock the cells in table, because in this case protected table can not be sorted by header. That the reason I don't use worksheet protection.